# Using minted in beamer creates a blank slide with the word "color" before the first slide

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm using the minted package within beamer and my presentation is starting with a blank slide in it with the only word "color" written before the presentantion slide. How can I solve this problem? Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{python}
class X(object):
    pass
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consult the log file. You might find hints that `-shell-escape` needs to be activated or that pygmetize is missing. If that is the case:

1. Install Pygments: `pip install Pygments`
2. Add the `-shell-escape` flag to your latex command.

Comment: `Pygments` is installed, and `shell-escape` is flagged to my latex command.

Comment: @José: any minted/pygmentize related errors in the log file?

Comment: I found it, thanks to your suggestion, @killozap! I had to reinstall mint linux im my VMWare Player and found out that the latex beamer files freshly compiled didn't showed the blank first transparency. I ran diff in an old log beamer latex file and the freshly compiled and found out that the old one was calling and old version of the minted package I had in a directory in my latex path from decades ago. I had only to eliminate it from this directory and all is fine now. _Voilà!_